# How to speed up date/time parsing?

Tags: parsing, matlab, csv

I have a rather large CSV that I want to import into MATLAB. I used to treat datetime values as text, and the parsing was fast. Now I've started using a format string for `datetime`, and the parsing takes something close to a minute - not a lot, but annoying.

Is there anything I can do to speed up datetime parsing used in the Import Data tool?

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines of code you use to parse the CSV?

Comment: I'm not using any code - I'm using the Import Data tool.

Comment: can you provide a few lines of the text file you are trying to import, as an example? Can you post code of what you initially did and what you are doing now that takes that long?

Comment: Not sure whether it will help, but you could try to still import the data as text and parse it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing a function to import the CSV rather than using the data import tool.  This will allow you to split the process of importing and parsing the data into two distinct processes.  You can then optimize them independently.

If you can't achieve the performance you need using the builtin date parsing methods you might consider writing a mex file to parse the file for you.  If you aren't comfortable with mex you can write pre-processing code in a language that is faster that Matlab (like Python, Java, etc...). Have this code convert the date strings into format that Matlab can quickly handle. Call this preprocessing code from Matlab and then import its result.

In the end you'll have to decide if its worth your time to speed up a 1 minute operation. If you're going to call this code several times every day then its probably in your best interest to speed it up. If you are only going to call it a few times a week then move on.  Use the time it takes to import as a coffee break.